# Не работает @media CSS

Tags: css

У меня не работает CSS @media query. В `styles` пишет `unknown property name` (неизвестное имя свойства). Как это можно исправить?

```
@media (max-width: 1200px) {      
    .intro__subtitle {
       font-size: 8px; 
    }
}
```

Comment: а где именно пишет? В браузере обычно ошибки по css не появляются - вы программой какой пользуетесь?

Comment: Пишет когда захожу Просмотреть код. Elements-Styles и там появился треугольник жёлтого цвета с знаком !

Comment: Katerina , я вижу, что вы во второй раз задаете этот вопрос - в прошлый раз вы  задавали его в группе по C# (рекомендую удалить - прослывете спамером). Я понимаю, что кажется, что все должны знать где и как у вас появляется ошибка, но попробуйте всё же объяснить подробнее. У меня, например, браузер Crome, у меня ваш код работает. Согласно сервису caniuse.com  @media знают все браузеры. Вы где смотрите - какая программа, какая версия? Может проблема в том, что вам просто нужно скачать браузер с официального сайта

Comment: Спасибо большое. Я переставила немного выше и вроде всё заработало. Я ещё не всё знаю, так, как это мой первый сайт )) Сама я работаю графическим дизайнером около 20 лет, а тут решила научиться верстать сайты. У меня ещё проблемка с адаптацией. Можете подсказать, что с моим сайтом? Когда смотрю на планшете и телефоне он уезжает влево. www.creativepd.ru